# Keyboard problems with Debian 7 64bit server

Tags: keyboard, debian

Running an Apple USB keyboard (the large one with a numpad)

I'm unable to use the ALT-key, so I can't access fairly vital symbols like: [] and {}.

Swedish characters doesn't work either, even though it's less of an issue.

I've followed the instructions here:
https://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard

But regardless what I set, I can't notice any differences (even after reboot).

The server is setup on a VPS so I'm using VNC to access the console. I'm using the built in Screen sharing client of OS X Mavericks.

Any help would be very much appreciated

/J

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't a keyboard problem at all.

Seems the problem is with the built in VNC client in OS X Mavericks.

If I use a Java client the keyboard works great.